# How can I resolve installer command-line switch value in Inno Setup Pascal Script?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to fire a S2S pixel from the installer when an install is successful. The pixel require some details like the IP, location, time and sub-id.

I got all the details except the sub id, which is specified on the command line using `/subID=xxxx` switch, when executing the installer.

Comment: What is "sub id"?

Comment: The Sub id is used to Identify which publisher sent the install for example if there are 10 publisher each will be using a different sub id which will be something /subID=xxxxx  they will be using this in the Command line now i need to capture what sub id used in the time of installation and send them back to the server using a pixel tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`{param:ParamName}` pseudo-constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=param).

See also [Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618257/850848).

In a Pascal Script you can resolve it using the [`ExpandConstant` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_expandconstant):

```pascal
ExpandConstant('{param:subID}')
```

---

If you need some custom parsing, you will have to parse the command-line explicitly by iterating the parameter list using the [`ParamStr`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_paramstr) and [`ParamCount`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_paramcount) function.

See some of the answers in the question linked above, and also:

- [Passing a string value to Inno Setup from command line app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/612609/850848)
- [Install files if command-line switch is passed to Inno Setup based installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46312588/850848)

Comment: (http://pastebin.com/0GRpVKx2) this is what i  have posted the codes in the question can you please help me edit that it works as i wanted. because the place you have mentioned i have something else to work also am afraid if i do anything wrong i might loose what i have now that is why. :-(

Comment: I do not understand, what you ask me for. Just use the `ExpandConstant('{param:subID}')`, the same way, you for example use the `trim('{#MyAppName}')`.

Comment: In which part of the code i have to make the above changes and this is what i have in the  NewInstallerPath:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Setup.exe');

Comment: Also please do not take it wrong if my questions are not perfect because am learning very slowly.

Comment: What does `NewInstallerPath` has to do with your question? You download the actual installer right? So you want to propagate the `/subid` switch value from the main installer to the subinstaller? Or what?

Comment: Not exactly, The code i have pasted is to the installer i have compiled the code and got it as a executable after that i will give it to 10 publishers each one will be using their own installer with a command line like this ( /Verysilent /Subid=xxxxxx) now i have to capture what subid they have used in their installer to executive my compiled executable and send it to the server via S2S pixel exactly where it says campaign.

Comment: So again, what does `NewInstallerPath` has to do with your question?

Comment: that is what i have in my code the guy who did the code is not with me anymore so that is the am trying to figure out to be honest i dont know for what it is used for. :-(

Comment: Well, then again, take a look at the `app := trim('{#MyAppName}');`. Introduce a new variable `SUBID`, like the `app`. And assign it the `ExpandConstant('{param:subID}')`. You already use the `SUBID`, when generating the URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124544/discussion-between-baskar-kumar-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: Well i have tried the same but its posting the Sub id instead posting an empty value Result : http://imgur.com/a/4PO3n

Comment: This is the new Code http://pastebin.com/KKLRDw0d also please see the images attached here ( http://imgur.com/a/4PO3n ) you can see what am trying to do

Comment: You never assign the `SUBID` variable! `SUBID := ExpandConstant('{param:subID}');`

Comment: Can you please tell me how i can do that

Comment: You are Great as always thank you so much. you are the master blaster