# How to make Inno Setup /DIR command line switch work with custom path page

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

When I use /`DIR` command line switch

```
"Mysoft.exe" /VERYSILENT /installerbusiness /DIR="C:\Program Files (x86)"
```

The specified path does not get used for path box on my custom page :

I'm using code based on [Use two/multiple selected directories from custom page in Files section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36317959/850848).

This is an example of the code I'm using.

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Install: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  Install :=
    CreateInputDirPage(
      wpSelectDir, CustomMessage('Readyinstall'), 
      CustomMessage('Readyinstallpc'), #13#10#13#10 + CustomMessage('Tocontinuet'),
      True, 'Mysoft');

  Install.Add(CustomMessage('DestFolder'));

  Install.Values[0] := ('C:\Program Files\Mysoft');
  { ... }
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the standard behavior of "installation path" of Inno Setup, which includes the processing of [`/DIR=` command-line switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=DIR), you have to link your custom path box to the standard one.

So particularly, you have to copy the initial value of the `WizardForm.DirEdit` to your custom box:

```pascal
var
  Page: TInputDirWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  ...
  Page := CreateInputDirPage(...);
  Page.Add(...);
  Page.Values[0] := WizardForm.DirEdit.Text;
end;
```

This solution handles not only `/DIR=`, but also [`/LOADINF=`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline&anchor=LOADINF).

To complement the code above, you should copy the value back to `WizardForm.DirEdit`. This way you make sure that on re-install/upgrade, the previously selected value is reused. This is shown in point 1) of my answer to [Use two/multiple selected directories from custom page in Files section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36317959/850848).

---

If the above is too complicated (or not obvious) to implement, because of a complex logic of your installer, you can handle the `/DIR=` switch programmatically yourself. See [Setting value of Inno Setup custom page field from command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45442551/850848).

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  DirSwitchValue: string;
begin
  Install := ...;

  Install.Add(...);

  DirSwitchValue := ExpandConstant('{param:DIR}');
  if DirSwitchValue <> '' then
  begin
    Install.Values[0] := DirSwitchValue;
  end
    else
  begin
    Install.Values[0] := ExpandConstant('{pf}\Mysoft');
  end;
end;
```

This solution obviously does not handle `/LOADINF=`. How to process `.inf` files is shown in [Inno Setup Load defaults for custom installation settings from a file (.inf) for silent installation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38624032/850848).

Also, with this solution, the previously used installation path won't be used for upgrades/re-installs. How to implement that is shown in [Inno Setup with three destination folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25657175/850848).