# How do we access command line switches passed to an Inno Setup uninstaller?

Tags: inno-setup

Can Inno Setup handle this?

How do we access command line parameters/switches passed to an Inno Setup uninstaller?

I'm trying to make a conditional uninstaller in Innosetup that can conditionally leave behind files.  I'd like it to be silent, hence the command line switches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ParamStr`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_paramstr) and [`ParamCount`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_paramcount) functions.

In case your command-line switch have a value, using [`{param:ParamName}` pseudo-constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=param) can be more convenient.

---

For some examples, see some of more specific questions on Inno Setup custom command-line arguments:

- [Is it possible to accept custom command line parameters with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3618257/850848)
- [Passing conditional parameter in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14392921/850848)
- [How can I resolve installer command-line switch value in Inno Setup Pascal Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39768999/850848)